# Dynamic library contains only metadata, no types

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, .net-assembly, typebuilder

Using .NET 4.7.2, I dynamically generate a `.dll` at runtime using

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("ModuleName");
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyNamespace.TypeName", TypeAttributes.Public);

        typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

        // Build the method 'public int ReturnTheAnswer() => 42;'.
        MethodBuilder newMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ReturnTheAnswer", MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(int), new Type[0]);
        ILGenerator ilGen = newMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 42);
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Type newType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        assemblyBuilder.Save("MyAssembly.dll"); // Save the assembly in the programs work directory ('bin\Debug').

        dynamic o = Activator.CreateInstance(newType); // Create an instance of the dynamically created type.
        int r = (int) o.ReturnTheAnswer();

        Debug.Assert(r == 42); // If this doesn't fail, the type has been built correctly, is in fact in the .dll and can be used perfectly fine.
    }
}
```

and I can use the type in the `.dll` perfectly fine, however, when browsing the generated `.dll` with DotPeek and IL Spy, they both do not show any namespaces or types (albeit they should show the type `TypeName` in namespace `MyNamespace`).

---

**Why is the assembly seemingly empty when using two distinct decompilers, but using its types from code works perfectly fine?**

(above example code is mvce, you should be able to reproduce the exact behavior I encounter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Type doesn't get saved because it is declared in a **transient dynamic module**.
`AssemblyBuilder`'s `Save` method only saves non-transient dynamic modules.
See the [**remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.save?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> This method saves all non-transient dynamic modules defined in this
>   dynamic assembly.
>   **Transient dynamic modules are not saved.**
>   The assembly file name can be the same as the name of one of the modules. If so, the assembly
>   manifest is stored within that module. assemblyFileName can be
>   different from the names of all of the modules contained within the
>   assembly. If so, the assembly file contains only the assembly
>   manifest.

To persist your Type, you must declare it in a non-transient **persistable  dynamic module**, using one of the overloads of [`DefineDynamicModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.definedynamicmodule?view=netframework-4.7.2) that accepts a `fileName` argument, like this:

```
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("ModuleName", "MyAssembly.dll");
```

Your full code will look like here below.
Use the same filename to keep your Type and the manifest together in 1 single assembly file.

```
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new 
AssemblyName("MyAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("ModuleName", "MyAssembly.dll");
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyNamespace.TypeName", TypeAttributes.Public);

typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

// Build the method 'public int ReturnTheAnswer() => 42;'.
MethodBuilder newMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("ReturnTheAnswer", 
MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(int), new Type[0]);
ILGenerator ilGen = newMethod.GetILGenerator();
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 42);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Type newType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

assemblyBuilder.Save("MyAssembly.dll"); // Save the assembly in the programs work directory ('bin\Debug').

dynamic o = Activator.CreateInstance(newType); // Create an instance of the dynamically created type.
int r = (int) o.ReturnTheAnswer();

Debug.Assert(r == 42); // If this doesn't fail, the type has been built correctly, is in fact in the .dll and can be used perfectly fine.
```